# objc_msgSend iphone application crash

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

Crash Report :

```
 > Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread 0  libobjc.A.dylib            
 > 0x306bdf46 objc_msgSend + 5 1  libAVFAudio.dylib             
 > 0x21ac3e71 -[AVAudioSession privateBeginInterruption] + 52 2 
 > Foundation                     0x23bb8d6f __NSThreadPerformPerform +
 > 386 3  CoreFoundation                 0x22e70377
 > __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14 4  CoreFoundation                     0x22e6f819 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 364
> 5  CoreFoundation                 0x22e6dded __CFRunLoopRun + 772 6 
> CoreFoundation                 0x22dbc211 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476 7
> CoreFoundation                 0x22dbc023 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106 8 
> GraphicsServices               0x2a16f0a9 GSEventRunModal + 136 9 
> UIKit                          0x263c81d1 UIApplicationMain + 1440 10
> HIIT GURU                      0x000d7377 main (main.m:16)
```

I am getting this crash randomly. I tried to check each line of code but i couldn't find any solution. Please suggest something to solve this. I am getting this crash in ios8.1 only.

Comment: The crash log suggests that you did not handle the audio interruption.

Answer (score 0):

This often occurs when the reference to the receiving object gets invalid.

Start with a static analysis of your code. Most of the times you can let Xcode do it for you through the `Product -> Analyze` tool. Also try enabling zombie objects while debugging through editing the current scheme going through `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme` and check the appropriate box in the **Diagnostics** tab. Once enabled you have to wait for the crash to occur again if you don't know how to reproduce.